# Why is 1100 matched by /(0*1(00)*10*)*/?

Tags: regex

I expected it not [match](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=109475).  I can see how 11 matches: you just take the entire RE once but with no zeroes inside, so you need 11 because that's not optional.  Now, how can we get 00 at all from this RE?

Comment: There are some online graphical views of regex. Here's one: [(0*1(00)*10*)*](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zUbawcM2mZfkTo6Q). As long as it matches "optionally", it matches. The regex matches many strings.

Comment: I don't understand that drawing.  How do I read it?  How does it help?

Comment: The drawing corresponds to your regex. `0*` is illustrated by the loop around the first `0` in the diagram, etc. You should try to walk through it step by step, as it will help you understand regex. In your case, you get the `00` at the end simply because 0* matches zero *or more* `0` characters. Thus the regex not only matches 11, but also 110, 1100, 11000, etc.

Comment: You did spot my problem.  Indeed: I can use 0 of 0*, 1 of 1, 0 of (00)*, 1 of 1 then 2 of 0* getting 1100.  I finally see it.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it's clearer now! You should play with that website with the diagram. Start with a very simple regex (like `0*` or `0?`) and see what the diagram shows. Then try something a little more complicated (maybe `[abc]+` etc. If you're trying to understand how regex works, start simple.

Comment: Special thanks for the educational instructions!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/YWgTsz/1

Comment: Your regex can equate to `1100` that's why it matches.

Answer (score 2):

You match the first 1. Then (00)* doesn't match anything so you still have a 1. Then you match 1 followed by zero or more 0's.  So you have 11. then 0* or matches 00.  So 1100.

- 0*1 matches the first 1.
- (00)*1 matches the second 1.
- Then 0* matches 00

Comment: What do you mean when you say "so zero"?  So zero what?

Comment: I mean nothing is matches for that part of the regex.

Comment: I see your answer now.  Your bullets look correct, but your initial paragraph does not.  Notice how you say "zero or more of 00" twice before matching the second 1.  It doesn't look correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

( : first capturing group

0 * : character 0  zero or more times

1 : char '1'

( : second capturing group

00 : characters "00"

)* : group matches zero or more times

1 : char '1'

0 *: char '0' matches  zero or +

)* All capturing group can matches zero or more times

So 1100 matches